# Creating a CSS tree with divs

Tags: html, css, joomla, tree

I'm trying to create this effect: http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_tree/ the problem I'm having is that the code I'm working with only outputs with divs. So no ol/ul. I'm not quiet sure how to do this. Here's is a snippet of the code I'm working with:

```
<div class="jr_fieldDiv jr_exteriortype" style="">
    <label class="jrLabel">Exterior type</label>
    <div class="jr_fieldOption">
        <input type="checkbox" name="data[Field][Listing][jr_exteriortype][]"
        id="jr_exteriortype_brick" data-click2add="0" value="brick">&nbsp;Brick</div>
    <div class="jr_fieldOption">
        <input type="checkbox" name="data[Field][Listing][jr_exteriortype][]"
        id="jr_exteriortype_cement-concrete" data-click2add="0" value="cement-concrete">&nbsp;Cement/Concrete</div>
    <div class="jr_fieldOption">
        <input type="checkbox" name="data[Field][Listing][jr_exteriortype][]"
        id="jr_exteriortype_composition" data-click2add="0" value="composition">&nbsp;Composition</div>
    <div class="jr_fieldOption">
        <input type="checkbox" name="data[Field][Listing][jr_exteriortype][]"
        id="jr_exteriortype_metal" data-click2add="0" value="metal">&nbsp;Metal</div>
    <div class="jr_fieldOption">
        <input type="checkbox" name="data[Field][Listing][jr_exteriortype][]"
        id="jr_exteriortype_shingle" data-click2add="0" value="shingle">&nbsp;Shingle</div>
    <div class="jr_fieldOption">
        <input type="checkbox" name="data[Field][Listing][jr_exteriortype][]"
        id="jr_exteriortype_stone" data-click2add="0" value="stone">&nbsp;Stone</div>
    <div class="jr_fieldOption">
        <input type="checkbox" name="data[Field][Listing][jr_exteriortype][]"
        id="jr_exteriortype_stucco" data-click2add="0" value="stucco">&nbsp;Stucco</div>
    <div class="jr_fieldOption">
        <input type="checkbox" name="data[Field][Listing][jr_exteriortype][]"
        id="jr_exteriortype_vinyl" data-click2add="0" value="vinyl">&nbsp;Vinyl</div>
    <div class="jr_fieldOption">
        <input type="checkbox" name="data[Field][Listing][jr_exteriortype][]"
        id="jr_exteriortype_wood" data-click2add="0" value="wood">&nbsp;Wood</div>
    <div class="jr_fieldOption">
        <input type="checkbox" name="data[Field][Listing][jr_exteriortype][]"
        id="jr_exteriortype_wood-products" data-click2add="0" value="wood-products">&nbsp;Wood Products</div>
    <div class="jr_fieldOption">
        <input type="checkbox" name="data[Field][Listing][jr_exteriortype][]"
        id="jr_exteriortype_other" data-click2add="0" value="other">&nbsp;Other</div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i am confused your code only allow divs? Do you load the content via ajax to a div with specific name? If yes then load the ol/ul content via ajax.

Comment: It's a component with Joomla so I'm sure it's possible to load the ol/ul just not entirely sure where to edit to make this possible. I think I'll search for the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although a list would be better, it is possible without problems to do this with divs too. It doesn't matter it the structure is

```
<ul>
   <li></li>
   <li>
      <ul>
         <li></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child parent">
       <div class="child"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

With some help of classes, you can easily style as if you had an ol/ul list structure.

Comment: Thank you Christoph! I do appreciate your help.

Comment: @CarlV You're welcome. If it did help you solve the problem, you can accept the answer by clicking the green arrow on the left. This marks the question as solved to the other users.

Comment: I hate to be a neusense I'm trying to figure out how to CSS this code. I've looked at numerous sites and no luck. I only need one parent group and one child group

Comment: Umm, if I can find it then as much as possible. If I can't then not at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should [override the template](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) that the component is using.